# NoteCalc - Calculadora con anotador - Devuelve "None" cuando se intenta modificar una operación anterior

Tags: python, django, vscode

Estoy haciendo mi primer página en Django para practicar.
Es una calculadora web donde podés anotar un detalles en las operaciones, estas se guardan, y además pueden modificarse o eliminarse.

Aún no resolví la cuestión de modificar la "Operations List", por eso todavía no habilité la función de eliminar.
Todavía no tiene estilos.

Por favor les pido que me ayuden con cualquier idea, opinión, colaboración que tengan.

Este es el código...

views.py:
La web carga bien, la función "calculate" pareciera no tener problemas.
Aunque desde el principio la consola CMD tira errores, por más que la página funcione.
El lío empieza en "modify_operations"

```
    #views.py - Directorio: C:\Projects\test\NoteCalc0.2\myapp\views.py
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    def calculate(request):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            request.session.flush()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            expression = request.POST.get('expression', '')
            detail = request.POST.get('detail', '')
            try:
                result = eval(expression)
                if 'operations' not in request.session:
                    request.session['operations'] = []
                operations = request.session['operations']
                operations.insert(0, (expression, result, detail)) #operations.append((expression, result, detail))
                request.session['operations'] = operations
                total = sum([op[1] for op in operations])
                print(operations)
                return render(request, 'calculator/index.html', {'result': result, 'operations': operations, 'total': total})
            except:
                operations = request.session.get('operations', [])
                total = sum([x[1] for x in operations])
                return render(request, 'calculator/index.html', {'result': 'Error', 'expression': expression, 'operations': operations, 'total': total, 'detail': detail})
        else:
            return render(request, 'calculator/index.html', {'result': ''})
    def clear_history(request):
        request.session['operations'] = []
        return redirect('/')
    
    def modify_operation(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            expression = request.POST.get('expression')
            detail = request.POST.get('detail')
            operations = request.session.get('operations')
            operation_id = int(request.POST.get('operation_id'))
            result =  eval(str(expression))
            operations[int(operation_id)] = (expression, result, detail)
            #int(sum([int(r[1]) for r in operations]))
            total = request.POST.get('total')
            request.session['operations'] = operations
        return render(request, 'calculator/index.html', {'result': result, 'operations': operations, 'total': total})
```

index.html:
El problema empieza a partir de Operations List.
No sé si el error está en cómo se asignan las variables en la plantilla, o cómo se procesan en el servidor con "modify_operation".
LLegué a un punto donde quedé perdido.
Lamentablemente la consola de comandos tira tantos errores que no se pueden hacer prints() para ir controlando el código línea por línea.

```
    #index.html - Directorio: C:\Projects\test\NoteCalc0.2\templates\calculator\index.html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Calculator</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" name="expression" value="{% if result == 'Error' %}{{ expression }}{% endif %}">
            <input type="text" name="detail" value="{% if result == 'Error' %}{{ detail }}{% endif %}">
            <input type="submit" value="Calculate">
            <br><br>
            <input type="button" value="1" onclick="document.forms[0].expression.value+='1'">
            <input type="button" value="2" onclick="document.forms[0].expression.value+='2'">
            <input type="button" value="3" onclick="document.forms[0].expression.value+='3'">
            <input type="button" value="+" onclick="document.forms[0].expression.value+='+'">
            <br>
            <input type="button" value="4" onclick="document.forms[0].expression.value+='4'">
            <input type="button" value="5" onclick="document.forms[0].expression.value+='5'">
            <input type="button" value="6" onclick="document.forms[0].expression.value+='6'">
            <input type="button" value="-" onclick="document.forms[0].expression.value+='-'">
            <br>
            <input type="button" value="7" onclick="document.forms[0].expression.value+='7'">
            <input type="button" value="8" onclick="document.forms[0].expression.value+='8'">
            <input type="button" value="9" onclick="document.forms[0].expression.value+='9'">
            <input type="button" value="*" onclick="document.forms[0].expression.value+='*'">
            <br>
            <input type="button" value="C" onclick="document.forms[0].expression.value=''">
            <input type="button" value="0" onclick="document.forms[0].expression.value+='0'">
            <input type="button" value="=" onclick="document.forms[0].submit()">
            <input type="button" value="/" onclick="document.forms[0].expression.value+='/'">
        </form>
        {% if result %}
        <h3>Result: {{ result }}</h3>
        {% endif %}
        <h2>Total: {{ total }}</h2>
        <form action="{% url 'clear_history' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="submit" value="Clear History">
        </form>
        <h2>Operations List:</h2>
        <form action="/modify_operation/" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Operation</th>
                        <th>Result</th>
                        <th>Detail</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for expression, result, detail in operations %}
                    <tr>
                        <td><p type="text">{{ forloop.counter }}</p></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="expression-{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ expression }}"></td>
                        <td><p type="text" name="result-{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ result }}</p></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="detail-{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ detail }}"></td>
                        <td><button action="{% url 'modify_operation' %}" name="operation_id" value={{ forloop.counter0 }}>Modify</button></td>
                        <td>Delete</td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
        <script>
            const input = document.querySelector('input[name="expression"]');
            input.focus();
            input.setSelectionRange(input.value.length, input.value.length);
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

urls.py:
También está el urls.py de mysite que redirige a este archivo de urls.

```
    #urls.py - Directorio: C:\Projects\test\NoteCalc0.2\myapp\urls.py
    from django.urls import path
    from . import views
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.calculate, name='calculate'),
        path('clear_history/', views.clear_history, name='clear_history'),
        path('modify_operation/', views.modify_operation, name='modify_operation'),
    ]
```

Así se ve el error:
[image: Print del error cuando devuelve None]

Modificando los "name" de los input, sucede que a cualquier valor que modifique, le asigna los valores de la operación listada debajo de todo.

Esta es la parte en el index.html:

```
    <tbody>
                {% for expression, result, detail in operations %}
                <tr>
                    <td><p type="text">{{ forloop.counter }}</p></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="expression" value="{{ expression }}"></td>
                    <td><p type="text" name="result">{{ result }}</p></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="detail" value="{{ detail }}"></td>
                    <td><button action="{% url 'modify_operation' %}" name="operation_id" value={{ forloop.counter0 }}>Modify</button></td>
                    <td>Delete</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
```

Esta es la función en views.py:

```
def modify_operation(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        expression = request.POST.get('expression')
        detail = request.POST.get('detail')
        operations = request.session.get('operations')
        operation_id = int(request.POST.get('operation_id'))
        result =  eval(str(expression))
        operations[int(operation_id)] = (expression, result, detail)
        #int(sum([int(r[1]) for r in operations]))
        total = request.POST.get('total')
        request.session['operations'] = operations
    return render(request, 'calculator/index.html', {'result': result, 'operations': operations, 'total': total, 'detail': detail})
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ESTO ES LO QUE MUESTRA LA CONSOLA:
(ES BASTANTE ILEGIBLE)

AL INICIAR EL SERVER:

```
C:\Projects\test\NoteCalc0.3>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
February 17, 2023 - 15:37:26
Django version 2.2.3, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

AL INTRODUCIR LOS PRIMEROS DATOS ("1" y "a")

```
[17/Feb/2023 15:38:23] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3001
[('1', 1, 'a')]
[17/Feb/2023 15:38:33] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 3499
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 196, in finish_response
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 111, in close
    super().close()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\simpl
e_server.py", line 38, in close
    SimpleHandler.close(self)
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 335, in close
    self.result.close()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\http\response.py", line 252, in close
    signals.request_finished.send(sender=self._handler_class)
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 173, in send
    return [
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 174, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\db\__init__.py", line 57, in close_old_connections
    conn.close_if_unusable_or_obsolete()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 514, in close_if_unusable_or_obsolete
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 248, in close
    if not self.is_in_memory_db():
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 367, in is_in_memory_db
    return self.creation.is_in_memory_db(self.settings_dict['NAME'])
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\db\backends\sqlite3\creation.py", line 12, in is_in_memory_db
    return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable
[17/Feb/2023 15:38:33] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 60985)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 196, in finish_response
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 111, in close
    super().close()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\simpl
e_server.py", line 38, in close
    SimpleHandler.close(self)
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 335, in close
    self.result.close()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\http\response.py", line 252, in close
    signals.request_finished.send(sender=self._handler_class)
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 173, in send
    return [
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 174, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\db\__init__.py", line 57, in close_old_connections
    conn.close_if_unusable_or_obsolete()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 514, in close_if_unusable_or_obsolete
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 248, in close
    if not self.is_in_memory_db():
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 367, in is_in_memory_db
    return self.creation.is_in_memory_db(self.settings_dict['NAME'])
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\db\backends\sqlite3\creation.py", line 12, in is_in_memory_db
    return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socketserver.
py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socketserver.
py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socketserver.
py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 194, in handle_one_request
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 145, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 116, in handle_error
    super().handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 382, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 184, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 288, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 345, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 358, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
----------------------------------------
```

AL INTRODUCIR LOS SEGUNDOS DATOS ("2" y "b"):

```
[('2', 2, 'b'), ['1', 1, 'a']]
[17/Feb/2023 15:40:25] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 3968
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 196, in finish_response
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 111, in close
    super().close()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\simpl
e_server.py", line 38, in close
    SimpleHandler.close(self)
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 335, in close
    self.result.close()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\http\response.py", line 252, in close
    signals.request_finished.send(sender=self._handler_class)
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 173, in send
    return [
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 174, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\db\__init__.py", line 57, in close_old_connections
    conn.close_if_unusable_or_obsolete()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 514, in close_if_unusable_or_obsolete
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 248, in close
    if not self.is_in_memory_db():
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 367, in is_in_memory_db
    return self.creation.is_in_memory_db(self.settings_dict['NAME'])
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\db\backends\sqlite3\creation.py", line 12, in is_in_memory_db
    return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable
[17/Feb/2023 15:40:25] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 60992)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 196, in finish_response
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 111, in close
    super().close()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\simpl
e_server.py", line 38, in close
    SimpleHandler.close(self)
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 335, in close
    self.result.close()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\http\response.py", line 252, in close
    signals.request_finished.send(sender=self._handler_class)
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 173, in send
    return [
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 174, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\db\__init__.py", line 57, in close_old_connections
    conn.close_if_unusable_or_obsolete()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 514, in close_if_unusable_or_obsolete
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 248, in close
    if not self.is_in_memory_db():
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 367, in is_in_memory_db
    return self.creation.is_in_memory_db(self.settings_dict['NAME'])
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\db\backends\sqlite3\creation.py", line 12, in is_in_memory_db
    return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socketserver.
py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socketserver.
py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socketserver.
py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 169, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 194, in handle_one_request
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 145, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 116, in handle_error
    super().handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 382, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 184, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 288, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 345, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 358, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
----------------------------------------
```

Y NO ENTRAN MÁS CARACTERES.

Comment: Puedo notar que en tu botón "operation_id" en la parte donde insertas la {% url %} te falta el signo de porcentaje antes de cerrar la etiqueta, realiza la corrección para descartar que solo sea ese el problema o ahondar mas en el asunto.

Comment: Puede que el inconveniente esté en que el For guarda todas las operaciones con los mismos "name" (expression, result, detail).
Usando name="expression-{{ forloop.counter }}" puedo hacer que cada input tenga un nombre distinto, pero no se lo puede identificar desde la función "modify_operation" de esa manera para llamarlos.

Comment: No entiendo por qué me cerraron la pregunta, pero creo que logré solucionarlo anidando los Form, dentro de las Tr, dentro del For, dentro del Tbody, cuando en teoría no se puede, de hecho VScode me da error, pero al momento de ejecutarlo funciona. Al menos según los testeos que hice. Gracias a todos.